# Comparing many means in JMP

Tags: t-test, mean, tukey-hsd-test, jmp

I'm trying to compare several sets of experiment data, by comparing means. I read there are several different tests such as *Each Pair, Student’s t* and *All Pairs, Tukey HSD*, which give different circles of different radius, an example shown below

[image]

How are the circles defined? How do I calculate the radius? And is there a rule what test one should use for what kind of data?

Comment: What kind of software is that?

Comment: @mbq, This is JMP. But is this comparison circle a general concept, not specific to the software?

Comment: This is a first time I see such plot, so I think it is native to JMP. BTW I bet SAS would sue for even thinking to implement this in other applications (-;

Comment: @mbq, I'm sure they'll do. But what applications are these plots for? Or what other criteria I can use to compare data? Basically I want to compare several data sets and find out which set is _significantly different_ from others, so I can exclude them in my future development.

Comment: I suspect the red ones are outliers due to various methods and radii somewhat correspond to confidence intervals; but honestly I have no idea what this mean. However the question is now properly tagged so I hope some JMP expert will give you a satisfying answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion of the circle construction in the JMP help/manuals. See [Statistical Details for Comparison Circles](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Statistical_Details_for_the_Oneway_Platform.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

those are post-hoc tests which should be performed after a ANOVA in JMP. I don't think you should take into account the circle, which are here I think for visual comparison.

If you have issue for statistical test: Clic on mean/ANOVA to obtain the result of the ANOVA, it will indicate if you have a statistical difference among your conditions/treatments. If the result provided below the graph is significant (in Analysis of Variance: Prob＞Ｆ　is ＜0.05 or lower), you can perform one of the posthoc test: choose one, not all of them. Choice may depend on your dataset or statistical reasons but I am not expert enough to provide you good explanation of all post hoc tests. Usually, in Biology, each pair student t test or Tukey HSD are used. Tukey HSD may provide less Type I error.
Tukey HSD results are detailed below the figure and give you groups such as A, B, AB, C, D, etc... Different letter will indicate conditions/groups that are significantly different. Results also give the detailed P statistic. This is the result you want.